# Is there a way to loop opening a specific website in bash?

Tags: bash, loops

I attempted to write a script that could open up all of the web pages that are in a text file. What I have so far is this:

```
#!bin/bash
num=1

while [ $num -lt 4 ];
do
    site=$(sed -n $num{p} endingtext.txt | cut -d " " -f2)
    google-chrome https://www.exampl.com$site
    ((num++))
done
```

My text file looks like this:

```
Disallow: /example1
Disallow: /example2
Disallow: /example3
Disallow: /example4
etc...
```

The problem with this script is that after opening up one of the web pages it stops looping. I was wondering if it was possible to get it to continue looping

Comment: Your script stops looping because Google Chrome does not detach from the process running the script. You probably could launch Google Chrome in the background with `google-chrome "https://www.exampl.com$site" &`. I also strongly suggest you fix all the missing double quotes from your script.

Answer (score 0):

I can do this from my Mac and it works like charm :

```
#!/bin/bash

site='https://www.example.com'
for n in ${site}'/example'{1..3}
do
    open -a "Google Chrome" "${n}"
done
```

Hope it's useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed issues with your script:

1. `#!bin/bash`

   Shebang must be an absolute path. It misses the leading `/`.

   Correct Shebang is: `#!/bin/bash`
2. Line 4: `while [ $num -lt 4 ];`:

   Loop is off by one as it will stop when `$num` is equals to `4`, and since it starts at `1`, will only run the first three lines of your input file.
3. Line 6: `site=$(sed -n $num{p} endingtext.txt | cut -d " " -f2)`:

   1. Either curly braces `{}` needs escaping for the shell.
      Correct escaping is: `site=$(sed -n $num\{p\} endingtext.txt | cut -d " " -f2)`
   2. Either use double quotes `"`.
      Correct quoting is: `site=$(sed -n "$num{p}" endingtext.txt | cut -d " " -f2)`
4. Line 7: `google-chrome https://www.exampl.com$site`:

   Also misses double quotes `"` to prevent pattern expansion with files (GLOB).
   Correct quoting is: `google-chrome "https://www.exampl.com$site"`

Now all these `sed` and `cut` calls here re-reading the entire input file for each line, to in the end, performing sequential line access; can be greatly simplified by using the POSIX standard `read` command.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

num=1
while [ $num -le 4 ] && read -r _ site;
do
    google-chrome "https://www.example.com$site" &
    num=$((num+1))
done < endingtext.txt
```

Or a compact form:

```sh
<endingtext.txt cut -d: -f2- | xargs -l -exec bash -c 'google-chrome "https://www.example.com$site$0" &'
```